# scrapyd-deploy not deploying project? Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I have setup a scrapyd Server. When I run the command `scrapyd-deploy`, it shows me the following message.

[image]

but when I navigate to http://10.2.1.54:6800/jobs it shows nothing.

[image]

Am I Missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The `scrapyd-deploy` function only sets up the server to accept crawl jobs. You have to schedule `spider` runs using the `json` api. The screenshot you have shared is the default jobs page once the `scrapyd` server has been successfully set up.

An example taken from the [docs](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#scheduling-a-spider-run) shows how to schedule a job as below.

`$ curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=myproject -d spider=spider2`

which returns
`{"status": "ok", "jobid": "26d1b1a6d6f111e0be5c001e648c57f8"}`